# lsystem exporter?

Tags: gratis, linux, math, modeling, geometry

I am looking for a program that can make 3D lindermeyer systems and export them into a common format like e.g. obj or gltf.

I don't want a full plant simulator but rather just a simple graph, no 3D geoemtry, no meshes, just a set of nodes and lines.

Something like:
http://weitz.de/lindenmayer/

But that can create the graph for a 3D structure.